# Why aren't there any pageTokens in the orgunits list?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

So in both the documentation and in the response for getting the full list of org units, we didn't see the pageToken.  What if a company has 2000 organizational units, will we get a pageToken in that care?  Will the api just return all 2000 org units in one swoop?

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/orgunits/list

Just trying to figure out the what the max list size is and how we shoud page through the org's in a company if they have more than the max list size.

Thanks!
  Hardwick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list call for the organizational units does not support pagination instead it returns all the organizational units for a customer in one "swoop".